# Type for each value and naming, anonymous structs inside struct

Tags: c, formatting

Here is little snippet from my `types.h` code:

```
/**
 * tick_t: is used to store and manipulate with time (tick count)
 * Unsigned, at least 32bits
 * 32bit number gives us 71 minutes resolution
 * 64bit number gives us 584'942 years resolution
 * Use OMFW_TIME_ISELAPSED(targetTime, currentTime) for time comparing
 */
typedef unsigned long tick_t;

/**
 * pos_t: Signed integer which holds position
 * In most cases even 16bit number is enough
 */
typedef int pos_t;

/**
 * num_t: Floating point number used to calculate 
 * Please note, if you want use fixed point or any custom
 * number, you should use operator overoading feature of C++
 * and also implement following functions for it in omfw/math.h
 */
typedef double num_t;

/**
 * step_t: Hold current step value
 * Only increased / decreased by one
 * May be signed, unsigned, floating point
 */
#ifdef OMFW_PRECOMPUTE_TABLE
typedef uint32_t step_t;
#else
typedef num_t step_t;
#endif
```

and here definition of struct in different file:

```
typedef struct {
    num_t acceleration;
    num_t speed;
    num_t pulseLength;

    int id; //index 0,1,2...
    int32_t letter; //unicode letter

    /** total resolution = motor resolution * gearbox */
    pos_t motorResolution;
    num_t gearbox;

    int pinSignal;
    int pinDirection;
    bool invertSignal;
    bool invertDirection;
} MotorSettings;

typedef struct {

    /** Motor settings */
    MotorSettings set;

    /** Maximum achievable limits 
     * Computed from "in" variables */
    struct {
        num_t speed; //v-max; max steps/sec
        num_t acceleration; //a-max; Max accceleration that can be used
    } max;

    /** Position data stored here */
    struct {
        pos_t resolution;
        pos_t curPosition;
        pos_t tarPosition;

        //TODO impl - when motor lose step, increment this
        pos_t curOffset;

        dir_t curDirection;
        dir_t tarDirection;
    } pos;

    /** Calculated and changed by program 
     * Used as indications to calculate realtime data */
    struct {
        num_t speed; //v = steps/sec
        num_t acceleration; //a = steps/sec.sec
    } cur;

    /** Used for Realtime caclulations and timing
     * Should not be used in other parts of program than realtime */
    struct {
        //tick count to turn off and next tick
        //cannot overflow
        tick_t timeTurnOff;
        tick_t timeNextMove;

        num_t firstDelay; //c0; depending on TIME_RESOLUTION
        num_t minimalDelay; //clast; TIME_RESOLUTION / maxSpeed

        step_t stepsToAccelerate; //nmax
        step_t currentStep; //n
    } rt;

} Motor;
```

I am doing one little project that I would like to publish soon, but I have few questions about naming:

- Is having multiple types for each value OK in way I have them? I hope yes, I tried keep it as simple as I knew, but we are arguing with friend about that - he thinks that we should add `omfw_` prefix to them and make them more general (eg. make `tick_t` just 64bits), but I want to make this code run fast on 16bit microcontrollers too and having 32bit timing is working good.
- Do they have correct naming? I added `_t` prefix as `uintx_t` have.
- Is it OK to have multiple anonymous structs inside main struct? There is lot of data in here and I want to organize them. Should I declare then as normal structs, even when I dont want to serialize them or access as single ones (except MotorSettings)?
- Do the structs and variables in them have correct naming?
- And last one. I am not native English speaker, so if there are any errors in text or code, I would appreciate if you let me know. Thanks

Comment: [This stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225386/if-i-do-a-typedef-in-c-or-c-when-should-i-add-t-at-the-end-of-typedefed) may be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef unsigned long tick_t;
```

> we are arguing with friend about that - he thinks that we should [...] make tick_t just 64bits [...] but I want to make this code run fast on 16bit microcontrollers too

Personally, I would never use the `long` or `unsigned long` types in production code, because they vary in size even between different 32-bit platforms. On some platforms, `int` is 32 and `long` is 32 and `long long` is 64; on other platforms, `int` is 32 and `long` is 64 and `long long` is 64. Rather than play a guessing game with my program's future portability requirements, I would write explicitly

```
#if OMFW_USE_32_BIT_TIMES
typedef uint32_t tick_t;
#else
typedef uint64_t tick_t;
#endif // OMFW_USE_32_BIT_TIMES
```

This is much more typing, but it conveys the intended semantics unambiguously: that is, *by default* I want 64-bit `tick_t`, but I also want to give the builder the option of using 32-bit `tick_t` in case it's helpful to him. In fact, this lets the builder pass `-DOMFW_USE_32_BIT_TIMES` on his 32-bit platform, or `-DOMFW_USE_32_BIT_TIMES=0` on his 16-bit platform if he really wants to.

---

> Do they have correct naming? I added `_t` prefix as `uintx_t` have.

FYI, that's a `_t` *suffix* (appended), not a *prefix* (prepended).

This is fine; but you are courting collisions with the standard library. For example, the standard library already defines `time_t` and `off_t`; if you get in the habit of using the exact same naming conventions as the standard library, then you might one day run into trouble when you need a name for an entity representing a "time" type or an "offset" type.

Therefore I would recommend at least namespacing the identifiers as `omfw_time_t`, `omfw_offset_t`, etc. (Also notice that I wrote out "offset" instead of "off", because it's clearer and the compiler certainly won't care that we're being a little more verbose.)

---

```
int pinSignal;
int pinDirection;
```

Surely `pinDirection` should be a `bool`. Also, in all cases where you're using `int`, I suggest being explicit about the expected range of the value: is an `int16_t` good enough? Could we get away with `int8_t`? I would definitely use unadorned `int` for *computations*, but here you're defining a *storage format*, which means it would be nice to clarify exactly how many bytes each field is expected to have.

---

> Is it OK to have multiple anonymous structs inside main struct?

Yes. But I do think it's *confusing* to sometimes have a multi-level access path and sometimes not. For example, you access one field as

```
myMotor.cur.speed
```

but another as

```
myMotor.pos.curDirection
```

Why is it not `myMotor.cur.direction`?  And why is `myMotor.rt.currentStep` not `myMotor.cur.step` or at least `myMotor.rt.curStep`, given that you're abbreviating `current` to `cur` on every other line of the program?

(Again, *personally* I would write out `current` and especially `target`; abbreviating them as `cur` and `tar` is more confusing than helpful IMHO. With `current` you have to worry about whether the proper abbreviation is `cur` or `curr` (I've seen both, particularly since `curr` is the same number of characters as `prev` and `next` and `last`). I've *never* seen `target` abbreviated as `tar` (although I have seen `targ` and `tgt`).

---

```
/**
 * num_t: Floating point number used to calculate 
 * Please note, if you want [to] use fixed point or any custom
 * number, you should use operator over[l]oading feature of C++
 * and also implement following functions for it in omfw/math.h
 */
typedef double num_t;
```

You don't explain which functions are "the following functions." Also, it might be more appropriate to write this as

```
#ifndef OMFW_NUM_T
#define OMFW_NUM_T double
#endif // OMFW_NUM_T

typedef OMFW_NUM_T num_t;
```

so that it can be specified by the user at build time as e.g. `-DOMFW_NUM_T=float`.

---

```
/**
 * step_t: Hold current step value
 * Only increased / decreased by one
 * May be signed, unsigned, floating point
 */
#ifdef OMFW_PRECOMPUTE_TABLE
typedef uint32_t step_t;
#else
typedef num_t step_t;
#endif
```

I'm suspicious of this code. Why is it okay for the step number to be a `double` (which is what `num_t` is)? At the very least, you should replace the word `num_t` with `double` here for clarity. But also, maintaining this code is going to be a nightmare without a *very* thorough test suite. For example, you'll have to be very careful never to use `++` or `%` with a step number, because those don't work with `double`.

Why not just let the step number be `int` and be done with it?

---

Incidentally, I don't know what the initialism `omfw_` stands for, but you should be aware that to a native English speaker it bears an amusing resemblance to "omfg". :)

Comment: Many thanks for nice answer. `omfw` is short name for the library name, but I may try to change it to something better. is 2-letter prefix OK? like `om_`(sorry I won't say you name, it's reserved :-D) Also I will use full names like `target` and `current` as you stated. I will rename `rt.currentStep` to `realtime.step`, hope it's ok.  The `num_t` is int when precomputed table is used and double when results are calculated like `sqrt(motor.realtime.step)-sqrt(..step-1)` so there is no need for `int->double` conversion. May I ask why `++` on doubles is bad? And thanks for correcting grammar.

Comment: If you needed fixed-size types, why would you write your own typedefs, instead of simply including `stdint.h`? Do you still need pre-C99 compatibility?

Comment: @ttdado: `++` on doubles isn't "bad", it just isn't part of the language.

Comment: @CodyGray: Not sure if your comment was directed at me or at ttdado's original post, but for the record, I'm assuming that he *is* getting `uint64_t` etc. out of `stdint.h`/`inttypes.h`. (If he's not, he should be.) But there's still value in using typedefs to distinguish `typedef uint32_t tick_t` from `typedef uint32_t step_t` and so on; it makes the code slightly more self-documenting. (It also makes overload resolution in C++ more like a mysterious adventure; but the OP is using C, so that's mostly irrelevant. ;))

Comment: Well, it was a response to your answer, but I admit to having not read very carefully before posting it. In particular, I ignored the code blocks and read only the words, so I didn't see that you actually were using the standard length types. I just saw where you were recommending against using `long`, etc. in favor of a `typedef`. Your argument in the comment makes sense, I suppose, but I'm not a big fan of introducing a plethora of typedefs. That just makes the code harder to read and understand, in my opinion, because I have to go look up those typedefs. But maybe that's the C++ talking.